# Multiple upload in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, file-upload

now i've tried to make a form field that implement some upload file. For example, i have an field upload such as A, B, and C in one form. and i wanna to upload all that file only for once submit and save the filename in mysql on the same column like this :

| id | filename_A | filename_B | filename_C |

im confused how to insert it to mysql. there is a way to make studycase like this?
i'll show u the code.
thankyou so much.

controller file:

```
function index(){
        $data = array();
        if($this->input->post('fileSubmit') && !empty($_FILES['userFiles']['name'])){
            $filesCount = count($_FILES['userFiles']['name']);
            for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++){
                $_FILES['userFile']['name'] = $_FILES['userFiles']['name'][$i];
                $_FILES['userFile']['type'] = $_FILES['userFiles']['type'][$i];
                $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['userFiles']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $_FILES['userFile']['error'] = $_FILES['userFiles']['error'][$i];
                $_FILES['userFile']['size'] = $_FILES['userFiles']['size'][$i];

                $uploadPath = 'uploads';
                $config['upload_path'] = $uploadPath;
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                if($this->upload->do_upload('userFile')){
                    $fileData = $this->upload->data();
                    $uploadData[$i]['file_name'] = $fileData['file_name'];
                }
            }
            if(!empty($uploadData)){
                $insert = $this->file->insert($uploadData);
                $statusMsg = $insert?'Files uploaded successfully.':'Some problem occurred, please try again.';
                $this->session->set_flashdata('statusMsg',$statusMsg);
            }
        }
```

models file :

```
public function insert($data = array()){
        $insert = $this->db->insert_batch('files',$data);
        return $insert?true:false;
    }
```

view file :

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label>Choose File A</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="userFiles[]" multiple/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Choose Files B</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="userFiles[]" multiple/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Choose Files C</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="userFiles[]" multiple/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="submit" name="fileSubmit" value="UPLOAD"/>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your are trying, I can recmommend dropzone to que your files and upload one by one. please find the example here. [rag-drop-file-upload-dropzone-js-codeigniter](https://arjunphp.com/drag-drop-file-upload-dropzone-js-codeigniter/)

Answer (score 0):

I really have a hard time to understand if this code does work at all (i think you are already in trouble, if you overwrite the global FILES Array)

Try something like this

Your Controller:

```
function index()
{
    $arrLetters = range("A","C");
    $arrDBData = array();
    $files = $_FILES;
    $countFiles = count($_FILES['userFiles']['name']);


    for($i=0; $i<$countFiles; $i++)
    {           
        $_FILES['userFiles']['name']= $files['userFiles']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userFiles']['type']= $files['userFiles']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['userFiles']['tmp_name']= $files['userFiles']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userFiles']['error']= $files['userFiles']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['userFiles']['size']= $files['userFiles']['size'][$i];    

        $uploadPath = 'uploads';
        $config = array(
            'upload_path'   =>  $uploadPath,
            'allowed_types' =>  'gif|jpg|png'
        );

        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if ($this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $arrDBData["filename_".$arrLetters[$i]] = $files['userFiles']['name'][$i];
        }

    }

    $this->file->insert($arrDBData);
}
```

And your Model could look like

```
public function insert($data = array())
{
    if (count($data) > 0)
    {
        $insert = $this->db->insert('files',$data);
        return $insert?true:false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Unfortunately, correct me if i'm wrong, CI doesnt offer a reasonable handling for multiple uploads. (I didn't found anything in the 
[Codeigniter Upload Documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html))

Answer (score 0):

[Downlaod this Codeigniter Library and put this file under application/libraries](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r6fcnoegg5v8vit/MY_Upload.php?dl=0)

Use Like this in your controller

```
if ($_FILES) {
        $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']      = '200';
        $config['max_width']     = '1024';
        $config['max_height']    = '768';
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if (!$this->upload->do_multi_upload("file")) {
            $data['errors'] = ($this->upload->display_errors());
        } else {
            $images = ($this->upload->get_multi_upload_data());
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($images); $i++) {
            $this->user_model->addUserImage($images[$i]);
            }
        }
```

And save the files in your model like this

```
public function addUserImage($image)
{
    $image_data=array(
        'name'=>$image['file_name']
    );
    $this->db->insert('user_images',$image_data);
    return true;
}
```

Let me know if you face any problem